# Gulp browserify order/sort files

Tags: javascript, sorting, gulp, browserify

I've got a Gulp task using browserify and watchify. As you can see I've got four files. `modules.js` uses the class from `overlay-model.js`. 
But browserify doens't keep the order I'm passing. Instead of that browserify puts the files in alphabetical order so it first uses `modules.js`.

I'll tried looking for a solution [gulp sort](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sort) doens't seem to work and I can't find a browserify-ish solution.

Anyone knows something about this?

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var c = gutil.colors;
var sort = require('gulp-sort');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var buffer = require('vinyl-buffer');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var watchify = require('watchify');
var babel = require('babelify');

function compile(watch) {
    var bundler = watchify(browserify([
        './assets/js/overlay-model.js',
        './assets/js/slider.js',
        './assets/js/words.js',
        './assets/js/modules.js'
    ], {
        debug: true
    })
    .transform(babel.configure({
        presets: ['es2015']
    })));

    function rebundle() {
        bundler.bundle()
            .on('error', function(err) { console.error(err); this.emit('end'); })
            .pipe(source('build.js'))
            .pipe(buffer())
            .pipe(sourcemaps.init({ loadMaps: true }))
            .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./public'));
    }

    if (watch) {
        gutil.log(`${c.cyan('scripts')}: watching`);

        bundler.on('update', function() {
            gutil.log(`${c.cyan('scripts')}: processing`);
            rebundle();
        });
    }

    rebundle();
}

function watch() {
    return compile(true);
};

gulp.task('build', function() { return compile(); });
gulp.task('watch', function() { return watch(); });

gulp.task('scripts', ['watch']);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think typically you'll have just one entry point (`modules.js` in your case) that'll use `require(...)` to load other modules in order you want.

```
// modules.js
require('./overlay-model');
require('./slider');
require('./modules');
```

Then use `browserify` like:

```
browserify('./assets/js/modules.js', ...);
```

Comment: Thanks, worked out! Didn't thought about this. I've tried it with import, but that didn't work. Some error about import/export could only work with modules or something like that.